# Cutting input with cut or awk?

Tags: linux, bash, irc, cut

I'm basically trying to parse raw IRC input with a bash script, and I want to grab the messages, and nothing else. An example of what I'm trying to save is

```
:user!~name@host.name PRIVMSG #channel :this is the message
```

So, I thought that this would be fine, and I could just use 'cut' for the challenge. I went on to use `cut -d ':' -f3` but soon found that if a user posted something with a ':' in it, it would ruin the 'parsing'
How else could I go about getting just the message?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a *range* of fields. To get from field 3 to the end: `cut -d: -f3-`

```
$ line=':user!~name@host.name PRIVMSG #channel :this is the message: all of it'
$ echo "$line" | cut -d: -f3
this is the message
$ echo "$line" | cut -d: -f3-
this is the message: all of it
```